# What is the effect of temperature during cryotrapping?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, temperature, chromatography, mass-spectrometry

I'm working on a lab report that has some specific questions that need to be included. The lab work itself dealt with GC–MS.

What is the effect of the temperature selected during cryofocusing/cryotrapping? What is the effect of making this temperature warmer or colder?

My understanding was that the gas based samples would adsorb to the sample loop and then rapidly desorb when the temperature is increased. However, I am not sure what the effect of changing the cold temperature is.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the temperature regime you of your cryo-trap.  If you are trapping in the temperature range from dry ice to water ice then you must be sure any significant water vapor in you sample has been removed.  If you are using liquid nitrogen, there is some danger of condensing oxygen.  This can be mitigated by using the enough-warmer-that-this-doesn't-happen-with-air liquid argon.